# Are there different ways to include makefiles using automake?

Tags: include, makefile, gnu, autotools, automake

I've been using GNU Autotools and I've observed that it is possible to include another makefiles with different methods, and I don't know and I haven't found anywhere the possible difference in the results or the way Automake manages the include, if there's any.

The different ways I've seen are using `include $(path_to_file)` and `-include $(path_to file)`, does the hyphen make any difference while including files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prepending a hyphen makes the inclusion optional.

if the included file (e.g. `Make.include`) does not exist, and you are using `include Make.include`, then the build will fail.
if, however, you are using `-include Make.include` the build will succeed (but of course the file won't get included).

i use this to allow users to modify the build without having to touch the real Makefile (cool if you are want to adapt the build to match your system, and you are using a VCS to track changes to the parent Makefile: this way the tracked Makefile won't get "dirty").

this is not specific to autotools, though, as it applies to `make` in general.

when using autotool, be aware that `automake` won't track anything nifty through include'd files.

Comment: Knowing this also applies to make, I searched in GNU make manual and it is documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include), I didn't find anything about it or any reference to this in the automake manual, so from now on I'll look in both of them before asking. As the GNU make manual says, you can also write `sinclude Make.include`. Thanks for your answer.